# How can I create Bookmarklet using is.gd API?

Tags: javascript, browser, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a Bookmarklet that will generate a shortened URL of the current site. I use is.gd API

```
javascript:void(window.open('https://duckduckgo.com/?q=shorten+'+document.location.href));
```

> I use DuckduckGo API here because "Body cannot contain is.gd URL." Please search for is.gd API if you want to know more.

This code will open a new tab and show the shortened URL of the current site, but I want it to work more efficiently, like *automatically copy the shortened URL to clipboard without open a new tab and have a JavaScript notification says that URL is copied.*

**Any idea how can I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you wish to make a bookmarklet that will use an API from https://is.gd to shorten a URL of document.location.href?

If so, here is a bookmarklet to shorten the URL of the current webpage you are at via is.gd API (simple format):

```
javascript:(function(){
    var func1=function(){
        var a = 'https://is.gd/'+
                'create.php?format=simple&url='+
                document.location.href;
        open(a);
    };
    func1();
})();
```

You mention DuckDuckGo API, but it cannot help you in shortening URLs, so it is better to use is.gd API directly instead.